# Why the line graph is not continuous

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I have 4 series of data in Grafana chart, but graph lines aren't continuous. Anyone knows why? Here is a sample graph with query:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that some data exists on a specific timeline whereas some data doesn't. So, for instance, in your case, your data that is represented as a yellow colour has something at 23:07, however, the one that is a blue colour has nothing in a database for this time. As a result, you have gaps in your timeline.

If you want to connect missing points, just change the `Connect null values` parameter from `Never` to `Always`:

[image]

Comment: hmmmm, it looks interesting, but I do not have null values in datasource table. Do You can explain why this solution works?

Comment: @sosnus, it means that some data exists on a specific timeline whereas other data doesn't. `null values` - is no data. So, in your case, your yellow data has something at 23:07, however, the blue one has nothing in the database at this time. As a result, you have gaps in your timeline.

Comment: Thank You, it's obvious now for me. I receive data in interval from a lot of queries and usually they have a lot of seconds delay